# Char* memory in data model gets reclaimed?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have the following code to read a credit card number from a text field and store it in a datamodel. The card number is correct when it is stored but later when I try to read from it it has become gibberish. Now I am guessing this is because the memory is reclaimed and it no longer makes sense.

Code to set the card number from the label:

```
        [cardInfo setCardNumber: [textField.text cStringUsingEncoding:[NSString defaultCStringEncoding]]];
```

Code in the data model:

```
    - (void) setCardNumber:(char *)number{
            cardNumber = number;
            //Value of cardNumber here is correct
    }
```

Everything looks correct until I use the property to retrieve the value at a later time.

Comment: How are you testing for the `char` array's "garbledness?" Are you converting it back to an `NSString*`, or using `printf`?

Comment: If this is a Core Data model - have you some reason to use char* rather than a NSString?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [docs for `-[NSString cStringUsingEncoding:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-BAJHJHHD):

> The returned C string is guaranteed to be valid only until either the
>   receiver is freed, or until the current autorelease pool is emptied,
>   whichever occurs first. You should copy the C string or use
>   getCString:maxLength:encoding: if it needs to store the C string
>   beyond this time.

Also, you should never use `+[NSString defaultCStringEncoding]`. It's completely unreliable and can't generally represent arbitrary strings.  From the docs:

> in general this encoding should be used rarely, if at all